# How to access the outputs in a workflow which are generated in another workflow template in argo

Tags: workflow, argo-workflows

I've a requirement to pass the Argo outputs back to workflow which are generated in a another workflow template

So I have ONE Workflow called `A` and TWO WorkflowTemplates called `B` and `C`

When I run my Workflow `A` it invokes WorkflowTemplate `B` and then `B` invokes another WorkflowTemplate `C`

The trigger flow is like this `A -> B -> c`

Now the WorkflowTemplate `C` produces the outputs as an artifact. I want to pass these outputs back to WorkflowTemplate `B` and the same should be passed back to Workflow `A`. So that I can use that output as an input to another task in the same Workflow `A`

The outputs passing flow should be like `C -> B -> A`

Is there any way in argo workflows to do this? Can you point me to an example?

Comment: How is A invoking B and B invoking C? Via `templateRef` or `workflowTemplateRef`? Or maybe with `resource` templates?

Comment: @crenshaw-dev They are invoking with `templateRef`

Answer (score 1):

Invoking a template from another WorkflowTemplate via `templateRef` works precisely the same as invoking a template from the same Workflow via `template`.

(Note: I wrote a [post on differentiating uses of the word "template" in Argo Workflows](https://dev.to/crenshaw_dev/the-three-meanings-of-template-in-argo-workflows-2paf).)

Here's an example adapted from the [artifact passing example](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/tree/master/examples#artifacts):

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: templates
spec:
  templates:
  - name: whalesay
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay:latest
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["cowsay hello world | tee /tmp/hello_world.txt"]
    outputs:
      artifacts:
      - name: hello-art
        path: /tmp/hello_world.txt
  - name: print-message
    inputs:
      artifacts:
      - name: message
        path: /tmp/message
    container:
      image: alpine:latest
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["cat /tmp/message"]
---
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: artifact-passing-
spec:
  entrypoint: artifact-example
  templates:
  - name: artifact-example
    steps:
    - - name: generate-artifact
        templateRef:
          name: templates
          template: whalesay
    - - name: consume-artifact
        templateRef: 
          name: templates
          template: print-message
        arguments:
          artifacts:
          - name: message
            from: "{{steps.generate-artifact.outputs.artifacts.hello-art}}"
```

Comment: it's not working for me for multiple workflowTemplates. Let me post a new question with the templates I created

Comment: Posted another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897648/unable-to-pass-output-parameters-from-one-workflowtemplate-to-a-workflow-via-ano
would you please look at it? I've posted the workflow templates and workflow which I created for passing outputs