# Unable to pass output parameters from one workflowTemplate to a workflow via another workflowTemplate

Tags: kubernetes, workflow, argo-workflows, argoproj

I've Two workflowTemplates `generate-output`, `lib-read-outputs` and One workflow `output-paramter` as follows

1. `generate-output.yaml`

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: generate-output
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main
      dag:
        tasks:

          # Generate Json for Outputs
          - name: read-outputs
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: outdata
                  value: |
                    {
                      "version": 4,
                      "terraform_version": "0.14.11",
                      "serial": 0,
                      "lineage": "732322df-5bd43-6e92-8f46-56c0dddwe83cb4",
                      "outputs": {
                        "key_alias_arn": {
                          "value": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:123456789:alias/tetsing-key",
                          "type": "string",
                          "sensitive": true
                        },
                        "key_arn": {
                          "value": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:123456789:alias/tetsing-key",
                          "type": "string",
                          "sensitive": true
                        }
                      }
                    }
            template: retrieve-outputs

    # Create Json
    - name: retrieve-outputs
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: outdata
      script:
        image: python
        command: [python]
        env:
          - name: OUTDATA
            value: "{{inputs.parameters.outdata}}"
        source: |
          import json
          import os
          OUTDATA = json.loads(os.environ["OUTDATA"])
          with open('/tmp/templates_lst.json', 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(str(json.dumps(OUTDATA['outputs'])))
        volumeMounts:
          - name: out
            mountPath: /tmp
      volumes:
        - name: out
          emptyDir: { }
      outputs:
        parameters:
          - name: message
            valueFrom:
              path: /tmp/templates_lst.json
```

2. `lib-read-outputs.yaml`

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: lib-read-outputs
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main
      dag:
        tasks:
          # Read Outputs
          - name: lib-wft
            templateRef:
              name: generate-output
              template: main
```

3. `output-paramter.yaml`

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: output-paramter-
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main
      dag:
        tasks:
          # Json Output data task1
          - name: wf
            templateRef:
              name: lib-read-outputs
              template: main

          - name: lib-wf2
            dependencies: [wf]
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: outputResult
                  value: "{{tasks.wf.outputs.parameters.message}}"
            template: whalesay

    - name: whalesay
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: outputResult
      container:
        image: docker/whalesay:latest
        command: [cowsay]
        args: ["{{inputs.parameters.outputResult}}"]
```

I am trying to pass the output parameters generated in workflowTemplate `generate-output` to workflow `output-paramter` via `lib-read-outputs`

When I execute them, it's giving the following error - `Failed: invalid spec: templates.main.tasks.lib-wf2 failed to resolve {{tasks.wf.outputs.parameters.message}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## DAG and steps templates don't produce outputs by default

DAG and steps templates do not automatically produce their child templates' outputs, even if there is only one child template.

For example, the `no-parameters` template here does not produce an output, even though it invokes a template which *does* have an output.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
spec:
  templates:
  - name: no-parameters
    dag:
      tasks:
      - name: get-a-parameter
        template: get-a-parameter
```

This lack of outputs makes sense if you consider a DAG template with multiple tasks:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
spec:
  templates:
  - name: no-parameters
    dag:
      tasks:
      - name: get-a-parameter
        template: get-a-parameter
      - name: get-another-parameter
        depends: get-a-parameter
        template: get-another-parameter
```

Which task's outputs should `no-parameters` produce? Since it's unclear, DAG and steps templates simply do not produce outputs by default.

You can think of templates as being like functions. You wouldn't expect a function to implicitly return the output of a function it calls.

```py
def get_a_string():
    return "Hello, world!"

def call_get_a_string():
    get_a_string()

print(call_get_a_string())  # This prints nothing.
```

## But a DAG or steps template can *forward* outputs

You can make a DAG or a steps template *forward* an output by setting its `outputs` field.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: get-parameters-wftmpl
spec:
  templates:
  - name: get-parameters
    dag:
      tasks:
      - name: get-a-parameter
        template: get-a-parameter
      - name: get-another-parameter
        depends: get-a-parameter
        template: get-another-parameter
    # This is the critical part!
    outputs:
      parameters:
      - name: parameter-1
        valueFrom: 
          expression: "tasks['get-a-parameter'].outputs.parameters['parameter-name']"
      - name: parameter-2
        valueFrom: 
          expression: "tasks['get-another-parameter'].outputs.parameters['parameter-name']"
---
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
spec:
  templates:
  - name: print-parameter
    dag:
      tasks:
      - name: get-parameters
        templateRef:
          name: get-parameters-wftmpl
          template: get-parameters 
      - name: print-parameter
        depends: get-parameters
        template: print-parameter
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: parameter
            value: "{{tasks.get-parameters.outputs.parameters.parameter-1}}"
```

To continue the Python analogy:

```py
def get_a_string():
    return "Hello, world!"

def call_get_a_string():
    return get_a_string()  # Add 'return'.

print(call_get_a_string())  # This prints "Hello, world!".
```

## So, in your specific case...

1. Add an `outputs` section to the `main` template in the `generate-parameter` WorkflowTemplate to forward the output parameter from the `retrieve-parameters` template.

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
   kind: WorkflowTemplate
   metadata:
     name: generate-parameter
   spec:
     entrypoint: main
     templates:
       - name: main
         outputs:
           parameters:
             - name: message
               valueFrom: 
                 expression: "tasks['read-parameters'].outputs.parameters.message"
         dag:
           tasks:
             # ... the rest of the file ...
   ```
2. Add an `outputs` section to the `main` template in the `lib-read-parameters` WorkflowTemplate to forward `generate-parameter`'s parameter.

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
   kind: WorkflowTemplate
   metadata:
     name: lib-read-parameters
   spec:
     entrypoint: main
     templates:
       - name: main
         outputs:
           parameters:
             - name: message
               valueFrom:
                 expression: "tasks['lib-wft'].outputs.parameters.message"
         dag:
           tasks:
             # ... the rest of the file ...
   ```

Comment: @creanshaw-dev - Wow, this is Awesome explanation. It works perfectly
I'm able to pass outputs back to my initial workflow for passing them as an input to another task.

But in my workflow `output-paramter.yaml` while am trying to print the output artifact in the task `lib-wf2`, it is printing variable as hardcoded value like "{{inputs.artifacts.message}}". Instead it should print my json result which am passing as an output to initial workflow

Comment: Oops, I wrote my whole answer to assume artifacts instead of parameters. :-P I've updated the answer.

If, after changing artifact-y things to parameter-y things, it doesn't work, can you add to your question the updated manifests? Probably something simple.

Comment: after updating artifacts to parameters, it's not working. It's giving this error `task 'output-paramter-p8gcs.wf.lib-wft' errored: output parameters must have a valueFrom specified`

But, I think I can use artifacts as well, but it's printing variable declaration instead of printing it's value, same  I mentioned in my first comment as well

Comment: @Biru interesting… I wonder if parameter forwarding just doesn’t work the way I assumed. I’ll test in a bit. In the meantime, wanna try with artifacts, but instead of directly printing inputs.artifacts.message, load that artifact to some path and then treat it as a file?

Comment: yeah, since parameters is not working, I considered using artifacts and loading it in to some path and treating it as a file. it's working fine now. But strange Parameters solution is not working

Comment: @Biru turns out you gotta use the `valueFrom.expression` syntax for forwarding parameters. Updated the answer and actually tested this time. XD

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a ton, it works perfectly

Comment: Woa such a game changing syntax ! love it !